# Sync Wordpress Articles from Local to Remote?

Tags: sync

I am starting a Blog and I am trying to keep my Localhost version as up to date as possible with my Remote server version on the web.

I would really like to be able to make a post/article on my Localhost install and have it somehow post the same article/post to my Web version (remote version) once I hit publish.

Does anyone know if there is a plugin or other method to easily automate or help with such a task?  My main goal is that I will have a Local and Remote version of all articles when I post them, I would prefer to be able to post first on my Local version and then publish the end result to my website/remote install

Comment: Post data is stored in the database, so you can't do that without a custom script that replaces the stored data to properly reflect the current site. Your best bet is to export/import it.

Comment: I'm currently working on a plugin that addresses a similar need. Basically what you need to do is use the post hook and use XML-RPC to remotely post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use [Windows Live writer](http://g.live.com/1rewlive4-web/en/wlsetup-web.exe??WLI=1&WLXID=0eebde2f-b482-49f9-aecd-92cd38cc3c05&RID=004c1d5f9d7&TID=1329212414030&lid=) and manage several blogs
from your home and get a preview on how the post would look like
in your blog pre-publish

Try it you gona love it!

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to post the same post to multiple blogs via WLW?

Comment: its not a built feature in but you can i guess copy paste

Comment: Also, there is no support for custom taxonomies in WLW